# How to display custom error message without using codeigniter session flashdata

Tags: codeigniter

On my project I am trying to create a error message for my session. I am trying to make it so that if session redirects to main page then will echo message that is on login controller.

> **Note:** I am trying not to use session flashdata if possible. ***I 
>   already know how to use flashdata***.

When I login to my dashboard it displays token in url

**Example** `http://localhost/project-session/index.php/dashboard/32118fa09a0ef2df16851d1f35e3f7d5`

On my dashboard __construct() I have this code below.

```
if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') == FALSE) {
    redirect('/');
}
```

The code above redirects session to home if token is false.

And if it has been redirected because session expires then below message should be activated, On login controller

```
$get_url_token = $this->uri->segment(2);
$get_session_token = $this->session->userdata('token');

if ((isset($get_session_token) && !isset($get_url_token)) || ((isset($get_url_token) && (isset($get_session_token) && ($get_url_token != $get_session_token))))) {
    echo "Session Token Invalid";
}
```

**Login Controller**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('encryption');
        $key = bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));

        $get_url_token = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $get_session_token = $this->session->userdata('token');

        if ((isset($get_session_token) && !isset($get_url_token)) || ((isset($get_url_token) && (isset($get_session_token) && ($get_url_token != $get_session_token))))) {
            echo "Session Token Invalid";
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('welcome_message');

        } else {
            $data = array(
                'token' => $key
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

            redirect('dashboard' .'/'. $key);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** Without using codeigniter session flashdata how can I echo my message in my login controller when it is redirect to login because session expire. When I am redirect the echo message does not get activated.

**Updated Login Controller**

> I have got message working but when I go to reload page it does not clear message. Any Suggestions.

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    private $error = array();

    public function index() {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('encryption');
        $key = bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            $this->session->set_userdata(array('token' => $key));

            redirect('dashboard' .'/'. $key);
        }

        $get_url_token = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $get_session_token = $this->session->userdata('token');

        if ((isset($get_session_token) && !isset($get_url_token)) || ((isset($get_url_token) && (isset($get_session_token) && ($get_url_token != $get_session_token))))) {
            $this->error['warning'] = 'Session Token';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need to see "Session Token Invalid" message in dashboard view. Is it not?

Comment: When it gets redirect to login controller if session expired then should show that message that's why on login controller.

Comment: try with `redirect('mycontroller/myfunction/'.urlencode($message)` and in you controller use `$this->uri->segment(3);`

Comment: @Saty I will inform you shortly. You give good answers.

Comment: No luck @Saty trying another way now

Comment: Maybe you could try with [Registry library](https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-registry/blob/master/Registry.php) that holds data all over application until you unset them. You could control that in constructor like you do with unsetting token.

Comment: @Saty I have added a update to my main post I can now view message when redirect. But when I refresh page it does not clear message something to do with isset I think

Comment: Ahh as i see you use `redirect` to send your token m i right??

Comment: @Saty I just updated if `($this->session->userdata('user_id') == FALSE) {` on post changed from token to user_id and message show OK. And once I have seen message and the reload/refresh page message does not clear.